# Need clarification for the Logical operator

Tags: r, shiny

Want to know if the below code

```
if((input$app != "") && (input$variable != "") && (input$variable != "All") && (input$variable1 != "") && (input$variable1 != "All") && (input$variable2 != "") && (input$variable2 != "All"))
```

can be written as

```
if((input$app != "") && (input$variable != c("","All")) && (input$variable1 != c("","All")) && (input$variable2 != c("","All")))
```

Comment: Are the inputs: app, variable, ...  characters or other types of variables?

Comment: If I understand you right, I guess you can do: `if(input$app != "" && !(input$variable %in% c("","All")) && ...)`